# Silverlight client access policy problem

Tags: silverlight, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a wcf webservice which I call from my silverlight application, using https, and it works fine without any problems.  Now I got to add a new reference to an old service (soap/asmx) from the silverlight client which went ok.  Then when I tried to access the service, I get the following errors:

***An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost/OldService.asmx'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services....***

Note: that the asmx service is using http instead of https.

My clientaccesspolicy file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from>
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it actually, I just made them all https.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use only Silverlight enabled service.
Silverlight works only with *.svc services, so you can not use *.asmx service in Silverlight project.